# SnowFlake PythonSheet Error :Could not find handler function. Python worksheet must contain a handler function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While executing Python code in SnowFlake Python sheet without the function

```
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return fake('en_US','celltype',{})
```

I get the error:
[image]

If I include the above function the code executes successfully.

Therefore, can someone explain the purpose of the function

```
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
```

I guess I need some understanding on 'handlers' as well.

The full code is as follows:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

from faker import Faker
import wheel_loader

    
def fake(locale,provider,parameters):
    wheel_loader.load('faker_biology-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl')

    from faker_biology.physiology import CellType
      
    if type(parameters).__name__=='sqlNullWrapper':
        parameters = {}
    fake = Faker(locale=locale)
    fake.add_provider(CellType)
    return fake.format(formatter=provider,**parameters)

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return fake('en_US','celltype',{})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main is the default entry point for Python Worksheet.

> [Writing Snowpark Code in Python Worksheets](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/python-worksheets#label-snowsight-py-worksheets-write)
>
> Write your Snowpark Python code inside the handler function:
>
> ```
> import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
>
> def main(session: snowpark.Session):
>     # your code goes here
> ```
>
> **The default handler function is `main`, but you can change it in the Settings for the worksheet.**
>
> Use the `session` object provided in the boilerplate code to access data in Snowflake with the Snowpark API libraries. For example, you can create a DataFrame for a table or execute a SQL statement

[image]

---

Important: signature of handling function (as a moment of writing this post) does not allow more arguments:

```
def fake(session: snowpark.Session, locale,provider,parameters):
```

[image]